# Understanding Measure in Path integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral, yang-mills

I know this is still a current topic of study, so my question is less about mathematical underpinnings, and more about the transition from the "sum-over-all-possible-intermediate-points" measure $$\mathcal{Dx} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \prod_{i=0}^{N} dx_{i}$$

to the "sum-over-all-possible-field-configurations" measure found in the non-abelian [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory#Quantization) for Yang-Mills, which I've been told has the form:

$$\mathcal{D}[A] = \lim_{N\to\infty} \prod_{i=0}^{N} \prod_{\mu=0}^{3} \prod_{c=0}^{N_{c}} dA_{\mu}^{c}(x_i) $$

where $N_{c}$ is the is the dimension of gauge group.
The relevant passages I found in Peskin and Schroeder glossed over the topic. (p.294 Eq. (9.50) begins the discussion, but it is for Abelian groups, where I imagine we can treat each component of Aμ as a scalar field, so the product makes sense to me (and the color product isn't present of course). I've yet to find a proper expansion/derivation of the same measure for non-abelian gauge configurations. There seems to be a brief mention of the functional integral measure around p. 665 Eq. (19.67) as well, but not quite what I'm looking to understand.)

Comment: Two good books: Montvay and Münster's *Quantum Fields on a Lattice*, and Creutz's *Quarks, Gluons and Lattices*. The components of the gauge field are associated with links (site-pairs) rather than lattice sites, and the formulation uses group elements rather than Lie-algebra elements. It is manifestly gauge-invariant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forget about gauge fields. Consider a scalar field $\phi:V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}$ for simplicity. The relevant equation in Peskin & Schroeder is instead
$$  {\cal D}\phi ~=~\prod_i d\phi(x_i). \tag{9.20}$$
Here $x_i$ is a point of a square lattice with a lattice spacing $\epsilon$, and $i$ runs over all lattice points. In other words, the discretized path integral measure is 
$$  {\cal D}\phi~=~\prod_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^4}^{\epsilon n\in V}  d\phi(\epsilon n). \tag{9.20'}$$
Does this help? Ultimately, we are interested in the continuum limit $\epsilon\to 0^+$.

Comment: I suppose I'll mark this as solved, I don't fully understand some things yet but I think that is due to a need of reading more.

A final question, can we treat in general, $d \phi(x_{i})$ as a differential, and write is as $\frac{\partial \phi(x_{i})}{\partial x_{i}} dx_{i}$ ?

Comment: No. The integrations are over the target space variable $\phi$, not over the spacetime variable $x$ per se.